# Windows Phone 8: C# XAML how to detect shape collisions

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, rectangles

I'm trying to detect whenever a shape (XAML), in my case a rectangle, hits another rectangle.

I tried searching for an hour now and still did not find something that helped me out with my problem. I'm also not using XNA so please don't provide me with a solution for XNA.

Just an example of the collision:

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the `Location` and `Size` of each of those rectangles.  The collision code is very simple.

A very simple example from [MDN: 2D collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)

```
if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y)
{
    // collision detected!
}
```

Comment: I'm using `Rectangle` instead of `Rect`, so this wont work for me

Comment: It sure will, `<Rectangle x:Name="rect1" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"></Rectangle>` Just take Left = x, Top = y.  It just requires a little bit of math on your part.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I forgot to use `Canvas`. I first of only used `Grid` which uses `Margin` for the position.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to those rectangles you could easyly use the `IntersectsWith`-method to look for a collision and the `Intersect`-method to get the size of the collision:

```
var rect1 = rectangle1.RenderedGeometry.Bounds; // get the rect struct
var rect2 = rectangle2.RenderedGeometry.Bounds; // get the rect struct

if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
{
    // get the area of the collision
    var collisionRect = Rectangle.Intersect(rect1, rect2);
}
```

This way you don't have to calculate the positions and possible collision manually.

Comment: Keep getting error `'System.Windows.Rect' does not contain a definition for 'IntersectWith'`

Comment: You're right. The `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`-class doesn't expose any intersect-method. But you can get the respective bounds via the `Rect`-struct. I updated my answer.